# How to reference and store properties of a class in another class

Tags: c#, windows-10-iot-core

I am writing a class for a device that has multiple hw inputs (one analog, two digital) and I want to use the properties from the HW class (ADC1, DI1, DI2, etc) in the constructor of my sensor class. How do I do this?

So I have a HW class that provides me access to my hardware. There are many more inputs, but a truncated version that looks like this:

```cs
public class HWClass
{
    public GpioPin INPUT1;
    public GpioPin INPUT2;
    public double ADC1Value { get => ADC1(); }
    private double ADC1()
    {
        //ADC code here
    }
}
```

I have a sensor that uses one analog and two digital inputs. I am wanting to use a class to provide some abstraction. Ideally placing the inputs into the class constructor. Currently my sensor class looks like this:

```cs
public class sensor
{
    private double AnalogInput;
    private GpioPin Input1;
    private GpioPin Input2;

    public Sensor(ref double analogInput, ref GpioPin input1, ref GpioPin input2)
    {

    }
}
```

In my main class I want to be able to assign the inputs to the sensor as I have multiple of the same sensor. Something like this below:

```cs
public class myApp
{
    private HWClass myHardware;

    public myApp()
    {
        sensor sensor1 = new sensor(myHardware.ADC1Value, myHardware.Input2, myHardware.Input3)
        sensor sensor2 = new sensor(myHardware.ADC3Value, myHardware.Input5, myHardware.Input4)

}
```

I want to be  to able store the constructor references and have a it work similar to above. How do I do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: When you say, *"have a HW class"* in reference to `HWClass`, does that mean you have control over its implementation? From a design perspective, hiding a method (`ADC1`) behind a property (`ADC1Value`) is a bad practice. You should remove `ADC1Value`, and then rename `ADC1` to `GetADC1` and make it public.

Answer (score 1):

A constructor can't take `ref` parameters.

```
public Sensor(double analogInput, GpioPin input1, GpioPin input2)
{
    AnalogInput = analogInput;
    Input1 = input1;
    Input2 = input2;
}
```

Alternatively you can provide an instance of the complex object.

```
public Sensor(HWClass hw)
    : this(hw.ADC1Value, hw.INPUT1, hw.INPUT2)
{
}
```

Or just store that complex object internally if you would.

```
public class Sensor
{
    private HWClass hw;

    public Sensor(HWClass hw)
    {
        this.hw = hw;
    }
}
```

Notice that value types are copied into the other class while reference types point to the same reference. If you want to store a copy of a reference type in the other class, you should create a new instance, for instance by implementing `ICloneable`.

Comment: I am a little green with C# and edited the question based on your feedback. Can you explain to me how I might be able to specify the the input to my sensor?

Comment: your constructors work as long as _myHardware_ gets instantiated somehow